# convert Uri to file path but can not open it in nexus 4

Tags: android, uri, fileinputstream

I open a picture in album and get the Uri. Then I convert the Uri to a file path. In the log it shows as something like mnt/storage/emulated/0/xxx.jpg. I covert Uri to file path as the way like:

```
Cursor cursor = GlobalObjectManager.getInstance().getContext().getContentResolver()
                    .query(filePathUri, null, null, null, null);

int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
fileName = cursor.getString(column_index);
```

The problem is that when I open the file with function  it catches a FileNotFoundException.

```
String path = "mnt/storage/emulated/0/xxx.jpg";
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
```

the code works well on other devices with Android 2.3-4.1.
So far as I know is that my Nexus 4 runs Android 4.2 and mnt/storage/emulated/0/ works for multi-user.

In my app I must use FileInputStream() function to read byte data of the beginning of the file.

Could anyone tell me how to fix the bug? Thanks!

ok i fix it.  I made a big mistake! I add mnt/ in front of storage/ needlessly, and it takes the bug.

Comment: I doubt that such hardcoded path would work, because different phones have different directory names. Try to use `getFilesDir()` or `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are seeing `/storage/emulated/0`. We're seeing this problem too, it seems to be related to the new /storage handling for multiple SD cards, I think it was introduced in Android 4.1 but maybe later.  If you look, you'll see that `/storage/emulated/0` does not exist on the filesystem, not even as a symlink.  Who knows what the system is using that path or what tricks are going on there.

The workaround is to do:

```
fileName = new File(cursor.getString(column_index)).getCanonicalPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have the "mnt" ,this is to say,you can  code as this:

```
String path = "mnt/storage/emulated/0/xxx.jpg";
```

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);

Comment: o no ,wo copy yours . Should delete the mnt