# Get complete path from URI - Nexus specific

Tags: java, android

We have a code running to convert the local URI path to a complete path. But the code doesn't seem to work on nexus series (android 4.1+ jelly bean).

**Code**

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = App.getInstance().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
```

I've read various thread on stackoverflow and the most relative one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517369/convert-uri-to-file-path-but-can-not-open-it-in-nexus-4) one. But even with the solution provided in it the issue is still persisting.

Basically the path returned by the code is something like this:
/storage/emulated/0/folder_we_are_trying_to_access

But in nexus there is no emulated storage. By trying to see the path from various file managers it seems like path is:

/storage/sdcard0/folder_we_are_trying_to_access

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I own a Nexus 4 and there deffinately is an emulated storage. The path `/storage/emulated/0/` exists on my device and works fine in apps I have written.

Comment: Thats strange. Basic we are trying to copy an image from 'Pictures' folder to app and due to path issue only, its failing.